# c# linq projection into method

Tags: c#, linq

I have this simple projection that projects Date to DateDto:

```
public static IQueryable<DateDto> Projection(this IQueryable<Date> source)
    {
        return source.Select(c => c.Map()).AsQueryable();
    }

    private static DateDto Map(this Date date)
    {
        return new DateDto()
        {
            Id = date.Id,
            EndDate = date.EndDate,
            EndHour = date.EndHour
        };
    }
```

Although this select query all the fields of the Date table (entity), which is not efficient.

This code snippet select only the three filelds I want, but I would like to move the select into aseparate function. Is it possible?

```
 public static IQueryable<DateDto> Projection(this IQueryable<Date> source)
    {
        return source.Select(date => new DateDto()
        {
            Id = date.Id,
            EndDate = date.EndDate,
            EndHour = date.EndHour
        }).AsQueryable();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your method to return an `Expression<Func<Date, DateDto>>`:

```cs
public static IQueryable<DateDto> Projection(this IQueryable<Date> source) =>
    source.Select(MapDate());

private static Expression<Func<Date, DateDto>> MapDate() =>
    date => new DateDto
    {
        Id = date.Id,
        EndDate = date.EndDate,
        EndHour = date.EndHour
    };
```

You could even just make that a field, to create the expression tree just once:

```cs
private static readonly Expression<Func<Date, DateDto>> MapDate =
    date => new DateDto
    {
        Id = date.Id,
        EndDate = date.EndDate,
        EndHour = date.EndHour
    };

public static IQueryable<DateDto> Projection(this IQueryable<Date> source) =>
    source.Select(MapDate);
```

Comment: Thank you! That works great! One more question. If I move the private static readonly Expression<Func<Date, DateDto>> function into separate file (same project, same namspace) it says: The name 'MapDate' does not exist in the current context. 

I have reference to the separate file from this code from other else. So I don't understand.

Comment: @JaczuraZoltán: Well yes, you'd need to make it internal instead of private, otherwise you don't have access to it from the other class. (You'd also need to specify the class name, e.g. `Projections.MapDate`.) That's nothing to do with expression trees - just normal rules of C#.

Comment: Oh. That is not an extension method. I did not notice, thank you.